# Rspec - Running setup for many examples in one context only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have just finished reading [Testing Rails guide by thoughtbot](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/testing-rails/master/release/testing-rails.pdf). The author mentions that using `let!` or `let` is an antipattern because in your test you dont get to see the variables that are needed for the setup.

I have this one common case that I'm curious how to deal with however if lets would be removed. I'm creating tests for creating a cart. When a cart is created, many things are tested. The current test is as follows (I removed the implementation of some methods and just kept the structure for brevity):

```
RSpec.describe Mutations::Carts::CreateCart, type: :request do
    context 'Sending a request with an unauthorized user' do
      it 'Creates a new cart and set the table for it' do
        # Test setup
        store = create :store
        branch = store.branches.first
        table = create :table, branch: branch
        create_dependencies_for_create_cart(store)

        cart_count_before_request = Cart.count

        # Exercise
        send_create_cart(store.id, table.id)

        # Verify: (Some expects)
      end

      it 'Returns the branch id and and the table id' do
        # Test setup
        store = create :store
        branch = store.branches.first
        table = create :table, branch: branch
        create_dependencies_for_create_cart(store)

        # Exercise
        send_create_cart(store.id, table.id)

        # Verify: Some expects
      end
  end

  private

  def send_create_cart(store_id, table_id)
    # Prepare and send the request
  end


  def create_dependencies_for_create_cart(store)
     # Creating some objects that need to be created before the cart is created
  end
end
```

**My problem here is that the test setup is common and needs to only run once. Also the request can be sent once.**

One tiny improvement over this would be to add a `before(:each)`. This would on the one hand DRY the code a bit, but on the other hand, I'm still running the setup + exercise twice potentially slowing my tests down, and I'm making the test less readable. `before(:all)` would at least ensure that the setup and exercise are only run once, still this is deperacted and recommended against by the Ruby community.

What's the clean and effecient way (both readable and requires no repeated setups) to test such cases?

Answer (score 2):

All `create` should be set via `let`. Keep in mind that all your specs must be independent all the time. No matter the order they have been run.
If you've a test that checks if a new cart has be created. That's one test. Another one might be to check the response.

Even if best practices say it's better to have a single `expect` per spec, sometime it makes sense to have several. It's all about context and logical for other dev to debug your code later on.

Here is my proposition:

```rb
context 'Sending a request with an unauthorized user' do
  subject { send_create_cart(store.id, table.id) }

  let(:store) { create(:store) }
  let(:branch) { create(:branch, store: store)} # check according to your association
  let!(:table) { create(:table, branch: branch) }
  # Create dependencies for cart here, on `let` too.
  # use `!` to force creation
  # Here only `table` has `!` since other variable are called to create this one.

  it 'Creates a new cart and set the table for it' do
    expect{ subject }.to change { Cart.count }.by(1)
  end

  it 'Returns the branch id and and the table id' do
    expect(subject).to eq([branch.id, table.id])
  end

  private

  def send_create_cart(store_id, table_id)
    # Prepare and send the request
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I really like the layout, specially that I have never used subject before. But does the setup here run once or twice? Meaning does it run once before the two tests are run, or does it run once for each test?

Comment: My main point is, throughout the test suite, there are many cases where we have to run some setup code, run an exercise, and then have many verify statements. Now, if in each of those cases the setup is run for each example and the request gets sent for each example this would slow things down considerably. It just makes sense for me to look for a layout where the setup runs only once. Any opinions on this?

Comment: It runs twice. That were my point when I said "sometime it makes sense to have several [expect on the same spec]". As long as it's maintainable (=understandable) easily by other devs, I don't see any objection to have several `expect` in the same spec. Especially it's your testing behaviour + response (2 separate things).

Comment: Each `it` is separate from another and run the whole context again.

Comment: As layout I really like it. As for the processing time I'm not sure. Create in let, persists to the db. Suppose I have 5 its, this means that I'll add to the database and remove from it 5 times, when one time as far as the logic not the layout is concerned would do

Comment: Gave the bounty because this was a very helpful answer :D 
Still think it misses the point on speed

Comment: If you think those 5 "it" are logical to be together, you can merge them (=less "it" -> faster). That's own specs works. You want a clean db for each test with a specific configuration. This is to avoid conflict and dependencies between each tests. It takes time but it's the best way to be 100% sure of what you're testing. 

Comment: What I mean is, in so many cases readibiiity and documentation require many its. Setup and Exercise need only to run once in those contexts. After some extra research I think the solution would be before(:all) without lets. The variables can be defined as instance variables using @, @store for example to be used throughout. What do you think about this?

Comment: `before(:all)` does not change your problem. I agree with your idea. I'm not sure it's possible to test it that way with Rails. I would break the independence test logic.

Comment: This is for the variables that need to be set once. And for things like test reqeuests for example where the test does not alter the state

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be using a describe with a context with a different describes inside it each having its own before do.

```
describe 'Sending a request' do
 context ' with an unauthorized user' do
  store = create :restaurant
  branch = store.branches.first
  table = create :table, branch: branch
  describe 'creating cart and table' do
    before do
      create_dependencies(store)

      cart_count_before_request = Cart.count

      # Exercise
      send_create_cart()
    end
    it 'should not create a cart' do
      # Verify: (Some expects)
    end

    it 'returns the ids'do
      # Verify: Some expects
    end
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. 

I really like this setup, but the problem is rspec wont allow it. Using create of a factory is only allowed within an it or before block. Now putting everything in the before do block would actually work. But everything in the before do block would run before each test slowing things down.

Comment: Actually what I'm looking for is some block to put the first 3 lines in that would only run once. So if we can just find something to run the first 3 lines without a re-run, this would solve it

Comment: @mrateb did you try re-running the before_do block in the first describe?

Comment: Do you mean inserting the first 3 lines in the before do block?

Comment: @mrateb yes, they would solve it

Comment: you are right, this would work. Still the root issue would remain. Tried byebug in the before do block, and weather or not the before do is inside the context or the describe block, everything in it would still run before each of the examples. Would have been content with the result if it ran once, but since it would run everytime wouldnt keeping the code in each test be better to see the setup of each

Comment: @mrateb maybe you can check using before_suite?